# Pyro Gaussian processes regression achieves a low error, but then always outputs the same prediction on new data

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, high-dimensional

I have tried experimenting with high dimensional Gaussian processes multiple times and I always get the same result. The model trains, and then when it comes time to predict with some new data (or even with the training data) it outputs the same prediction for every point. I have witnessed this in different libraries (gpytorch and pyro) so I must be doing something wrong or not understanding part of the process...

For reference, here is a recent try with pyro where I modified the code on their website to fit my data. The example code comes from here (http://pyro.ai/examples/gp.html#Imports)

```py
import pyro  # type: ignore
import pyro.contrib.gp as gp  # type: ignore
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from tqdm import tqdm, trange  # type: ignore

from .dataloader import GPLoader

device = torch.device("cuda:1")


def train() -> None:
    dataset = GPLoader(["2017"], device)

    kernel = gp.kernels.RBF(input_dim=707)
    gpr = gp.models.GPRegression(
        dataset.x.to(device), dataset.y.squeeze(1).to(device), kernel
    ).to(device)

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(gpr.parameters(), lr=5)
    loss_fn = pyro.infer.Trace_ELBO().differentiable_loss

    loss_log = tqdm(desc="Losses", leave=False, position=1)
    for i in trange(100, desc="Iter", position=0, leave=False):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        loss = loss_fn(gpr.model, gpr.guide)
        loss.backward()
        loss_log.set_description(f"loss: {loss.item()}")

        optimizer.step()

    test_set = GPLoader(["2017"], device)
    dataloader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=16)

    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(tqdm(dataloader, desc="Test", leave=False, position=1)):
        mu, sigma = gpr(x)
        print(mu, sigma)
```

can anyone explain why this is happening?

EDIT: here I am running the same data through gpytorch and I get the same result...

````
import pyro  # type: ignore
import pyro.contrib.gp as gp  # type: ignore
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from tqdm import tqdm, trange  # type: ignore

from .dataloader import GPLoader

device = torch.device("cuda:1")


def train() -> None:
    dataset = GPLoader(["2017"], device)

    kernel = gp.kernels.RBF(input_dim=707)
    gpr = gp.models.GPRegression(
        dataset.x.to(device), dataset.y.squeeze(1).to(device), kernel
    ).to(device)

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(gpr.parameters(), lr=5)
    loss_fn = pyro.infer.Trace_ELBO().differentiable_loss

    loss_log = tqdm(desc="Losses", leave=False, position=1)
    for i in trange(100, desc="Iter", position=0, leave=False):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        loss = loss_fn(gpr.model, gpr.guide)
        loss.backward()
        loss_log.set_description(f"loss: {loss.item()}")

        optimizer.step()

    test_set = GPLoader(["2017"], device)
    dataloader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=16)

    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(tqdm(dataloader, desc="Test", leave=False, position=1)):
        mu, sigma = gpr(x)
        print(mu, sigma)

```
````

Comment: Have you plotted predictions on the training data? Can you tell us what hyperparameters it's finding?

Comment: @KevinYang training data gives the same prediction for every point as well. How can I show the hyperparameters its finding?

Comment: In gpytorch, it's the `gpr.parameters()`. My guess is that your posterior is concentrating on a kernel with very long or very short length-scales such that nothing covaries with anything else. It's hard to say more without seeing your data though.